# Bootstrap tooltip not displaying for button within table cell

Tags: javascript, html, tooltip, bootstrap-5

I have a button for each row in a table of values that opens a modal when clicked. I need to have the button display a tooltip on mouseover and on getfocus. Here is a simplified sample of the HTML in question.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table id="table" class="text-left table table-home ml-0 mt-5 table_edit" data-toggle="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" class="text-center"><u data-toggle="tooltip" title="User name">User</u></th>
      <th scope="col" class="text-center"><u data-toggle="tooltip" title="User role">Role</u></th>
      <th scope="col" class="text-center"><u data-toggle="tooltip" title="Change the user role">Edit Role</u></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td class="table-row user-table-data">joetest</td>
    <td class="table-row user-table-data text-center">Admin</td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Click to update user role">
        <button type="button" class="btn trn-outline-primary p-1" id="edit_role_btn" name="edit_role" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#updateUserRole" 
                data-userid="joetest" data-currentrolecode="Admin">
          <i class="fa fa-lg fa-2x fa-cog p-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
      </span>
    </td>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

I have used the `data-toggle="tooltip"` with other buttons outside of the table and it works just fine. But within the table all I get is a generic non-Bootstrap tooltip on mouseover, and nothing on getfocus.

Comment: The bootstrap tooltip is showing when I tried. Did you initialize the tooltips inside the table? See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/#example-enable-tooltips-everywhere

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation for Tooltips](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/tooltips/#overview):

> - Tooltips are opt-in for performance reasons, so **you must initialize them yourself.**

> As mentioned above, you must initialize tooltips before they can be used. One way to initialize all tooltips on a page would be to select them by their `data-bs-toggle` attribute, like so:
>
> ```js
> const tooltipTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]')
> const tooltipList = [...tooltipTriggerList].map(tooltipTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
> ```

In the example HTML you provide, you seem to be using `data-toggle` instead of `data-bs-toggle`, so we can adapt it slightly as such:

```js
const tooltipTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-toggle="tooltip"]')
const tooltipList = [...tooltipTriggerList].map(tooltipTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl))
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-z3gLpd7yknf1YoNbCzqRKc4qyor8gaKU1qmn+CShxbuBusANI9QpRohGBreCFkKxLhei6S9CQXFEbbKuqLg0DA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table id="table" class="text-left table table-home ml-0 mt-5 table_edit" data-toggle="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" class="text-center"><u data-toggle="tooltip" title="User name">User</u></th>
      <th scope="col" class="text-center"><u data-toggle="tooltip" title="User role">Role</u></th>
      <th scope="col" class="text-center"><u data-toggle="tooltip" title="Change the user role">Edit Role</u></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td class="table-row user-table-data">joetest</td>
    <td class="table-row user-table-data text-center">Admin</td>
    <td class="text-center">
      <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Click to update user role">
        <button type="button" class="btn trn-outline-primary p-1" id="edit_role_btn" name="edit_role" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#updateUserRole" 
                data-userid="joetest" data-currentrolecode="Admin">
          <i class="fa fa-lg fa-2x fa-cog p-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>
      </span>
    </td>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I see that your code snippet works the way I want it to...but it's not working for me. I wonder if it has anything to do with the way the table is rendered, as a dynamic set of database records over multiple rows. Is there some requirement for the button to have a unique name or id?

Comment: You'd want to ensure the `bootstrap.Tooltip` gets constructed with the any relevant newly rendered elements after the table renders. The JavaScript code is not "reactive". It takes a snapshot of the current elements in the document that matches `[data-toggle="tooltip"]` and adds the tooltip functionality to them. Thus, if the table renders *after* this script is executed, you'd need to run search for the new `[data-toggle="tooltip"]` elements and construct more  `bootstrap.Tooltip` objects with these new elements.